# Return type of dynamic_cast upon failure

Tags: c++, c++11

Upon failure, `dynamic_cast` return 0 as the `NULL` pointer. Since c++11 and `nullptr`, why is the deprecated macro still used? Are there any plans to incorporate `nullptr` or is there an alternative to `dynamic_cast` that uses the new syntax facilities? If `nullptr` was used, would it break old code?

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments (and proven in the answers) the

> return 0 as the NULL pointer

is bad wording found in many c++ books (see the comments). Please refer to answers/comments for explanation of what actually happens upon failure of the `dynamic_cast` operator

Comment: "The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type." Nothing here about `NULL` or `0`

Comment: Brian's quote is from [expr.dynamic.cast]/9, the section where the behavior of `dynamic_cast` is described. Where are you getting your information from?

Comment: Stephen Prata C++ Primer Plus-Addison Wesley Professional(2011) - page 935 : _...If it can, the operator returns the address of the object. Otherwise it returns 0, the null pointer._

Comment: @Nikos That book is mentioned as not being a particularly good reference in the [C++ books list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou That's just poor wording on the author's part then.  They should have simply elided `0, ` so it read `Otherwise it returns the null pointer`.

Comment: @Praetorian C++ Primer (mentioned in the list), chapter 19.2.1 : _If a dynamic_cast to a pointer type fails, the result is 0._

Comment: @Nikos Now you've made me dig up the C++03 standard - *The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type. A failed cast to reference type throws bad_cast*. Nothing in there about `NULL` either.

Comment: @jamessan I agree that the wording is poor. I was revising the cast operators (there was a dispute at work) and kept falling on the same wording. ecatmur's answer makes a strong point on why `nullptr` wouldn't work and ofcourse (as Praetorian pointed out) the Standard ellegantly avoids zeroes. It's just weird how many authors oversimplify this (firing up pointless debates)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nullptr` is a prvalue literal of type `nullptr_t`. In the cases where it is possible for `dynamic_cast` to return a null pointer value (i.e. rather than throwing `std::bad_cast`), it returns a pointer type, which is not the type `nullptr_t`. Since C++ is a statically typed language, it is not possible for `dynamic_cast` to change its return type at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an example will make it clearer:

```
B * b = new B;
A * a = dynamic_cast<A *>(b);
```

The type of the result of the `dynamic_cast` is `A *` and nothing can change that.